# How to connect two Database servers in MongoDB and generate a report from two collections and joining them?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two MongoDB database servers and I need to generate report joining two collections which resides into two different database servers. Please let me know how to do it on javascript.

Comment: Well, you can't really make a join in MongoDB in the first place, since it's a non-relational database. Let alone joining collections from two different servers. Overall, this sounds difficult to me.

Comment: So you can create 2 connections to 2 servers and take material from one and use it to build a separate, second query to the other.   There's no real magic here.   The "join" logic is your javascript code.   Is this node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can join two collections from two database servers as follows:

Servers : S1, Database D1, Collection : C1, User : User1
          S2  Database D2  Collection : C2  User : User2

You need to write Javascript to connect two database servers and join the collections as follows:

```
Cat Connect_two_database_servers.js
    var rmtConn = new Mongo("<Server_name:S2>:<port>"); // remote host name & port
    rmtConn.setSlaveOk();
    var rmtDB = rmtConn.getDB(“D2”);  // remote db name
    rmtDB.auth(“<User1>“, "<password>"); // Remote User and Password
    rs.slaveOk()
    print("Organization ID" +"/"+ "Filter ID" +"/"+ "Rules")
    // Make a query from local database
   db.<Collection_name:C1>.find({organizationId: { $in: 
       [1332612387831813,453003085611340,1332612387831814,453003085611339,453003085611341,892807736721744]}, status: "A"}).forEach(
        function(filter){
                                  print(filter.organizationId +"/"+  filter._id +"/" +" No Fllter " +"/" + filter.name)
               // Make Remote database Call
               rmtDB.<Collection_name:  C2>.find({"_id":filter._id}).forEach(
                    function(bctemplate){
                              var val1 =     <Collection_name:C1>.broadcastContacts.filterIds
                              if (val1[0]){
                                          print(filter.organizationId +"/"+   filter._id +"/" + val1[0].valueOf() +"/"+ filter.name)
                                          } else {
                                                print(filter.organizationId +"/"+ filter._id +"/" +" No Fllter " +"/" + filter.name)
                                          }
                        });
 
   })
```

Run the program Passing Server 1 Parameters:

mongo —host Server_name Database_name  program_name  > output_file

mongo —host S1 D1  Connect_two_database_servers.js  > citizen_opt_out2.out

I hope this will help.

Comment: It works great. Thanks a lot. I was waiting for this for a long time.